MongoDB aggregation query with $lookup and $match
Context:
I maintain two collections: Package and Module. Within the Module collection, each document contains a field called packageId, which corresponds to the _id field of a document in the Package collection.
Sample document from Package collection
  "_id": "660dc62edb464b62c8e34b3b",
  "workspaceId": "6606a50d59b56908f026a3ab",
  "packageUUID": "6605b2ee536675159c565857",
  "originPackageId": "6606a51359b56908f026a3b2",
  "version": "0.0.7",
  "latest": true
}

Sample document from Module Collection
  "_id": "660dc62edb464b62c8e34b3c",
  "packageUUID": "6605b2ee536675159c565857",
  "packageId": "660dc62edb464b62c8e34b3b",
  "version": "0.0.7",
  "type": "QUERY_MODULE",
  "moduleUUID": "6605b324536675159c565869",
  "originModuleId": "6606a51359b56908f026a3bc"
}

My Use Case:
When provided with a list of module IDs (i.e., _ids in the Module collection), I aim to tally the number of packages that meet the following criteria:
Either the originPackageId field does not exist.
Or the latest field is set to true.
My attempt:
Here is what I attempted but it always returns 0
public long countPackages(List<String> moduleIds) {
        AggregationOperation matchModuleIds =
                Aggregation.match(Criteria.where(Module.Fields.id).in(moduleIds));

        LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
                .from("package")
                .localField("packageId")
                .foreignField("_id")
                .as("packages");

        AggregationOperation unwindPackages = Aggregation.unwind("$packages"); // tried without `$` as well

        AggregationOperation matchConditions = Aggregation.match(new Criteria()
                .orOperator(
                        Criteria.where("packages.originPackageId").exists(false),
                        Criteria.where("packages.latest").is(true)));

        AggregationOperation groupByNull = Aggregation.group().count().as("total");

        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                matchModuleIds, lookupOperation, unwindPackages, matchConditions, groupByNull);

        List<Document> results = mongoTemplate
                .aggregate(aggregation, Module.class, Document.class)
                .getMappedResults();

        if (!results.isEmpty()) {
            Document resultDoc = results.get(0);
            return resultDoc.get("total", Long.class);
        } else {
            return 0L;
        }
    }

I appreciate your help in this regard.

In general, the aggregation stages are used correctly. I created some sample data (note that I used only required fields and also, I used collection names instead of class names as I don't have class definitions from your post). I tried you code with appropriate changes to use collection names. I see a result as per the logic. I suspect your issue might be something to do with the Package and Module classes and how they are defined. May be some aspect of the code details, I dont know. I suggest you debug your aggregation with one stage at a time and see the expected results,.

[continued...] And then add the following stage. This will clarify why and which stage is failing.

One more thing, the result I got had an Integer type not a Long as in your code. My code was: results.get(0).getInteger("total", 0); and I got a value greater than zero.

I had used MongoDB version 4.4, Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.2 for my coding.

Thanks @prasad_. I am using MongoDB 6.x. However, I found that the results itself is empty. Let me check the generated query directly in the MongoDB.

Would you mind sharing the code that you tried? @prasad_

This is the closest mongodb native query reproduction that I can make of. The only change I am skeptical of is the exists. I need to replace it by comparing with null. You may want to check that part. Also, you may want to move the conditional checking into a subpipeline like this to simplify your pipeline and make it potentially more performant by reducing lookup.

From your code it seems that _id is treated as ObjectId().
match query is executing something like (extra "$oid" check)

[{ "$match" : { "_id" : { "$in" : [{ "$oid" :
"660dc62edb464b62c8e34b3c"}]}}}, { "$lookup" : { "from" : "Package",
"localField" : "packageId", "foreignField" : "_id", "as" :
"packages"}}, { "$unwind" : "$packages"}, { "$match" : { "$or" : [{
"packages.originPackageId" : { "$exists" : false}}, {
"packages.latest" : true}]}}, { "$group" : { "_id" : null, "total" : {
"$sum" : 1}}}]

However as per the provided document, I can see that "_id" is String. So declaring _id as string in "Module" model class executes query like below which returns the proper result

[{ "$match" : { "_id" : { "$in" : ["660dc62edb464b62c8e34b3c"]}}}, {
"$lookup" : { "from" : "Package", "localField" : "packageId",
"foreignField" : "_id", "as" : "packages"}}, { "$unwind" :
"$packages"}, { "$match" : { "$or" : [{ "packages.originPackageId" : {
"$exists" : false}}, { "packages.latest" : true}]}}, { "$group" : {
"_id" : null, "total" : { "$sum" : 1}}}]

Sample Module class:
@Id
@Field(targetType = FieldType.STRING)
private String _id;
private String packageUUID;
private String packageId;
private String version;
private String type;
private String moduleUUID;
private String originModuleId;


_id is an ObjectId() in DB. I have shown the sample document in a simplified format.
